# Change permission of mnt directory files

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I am not able to change the permission of files inside mnt directory.

Only owner (mysql) is having the rights to rwx but I am logged in using root still it is not able to change the permissions.

Is there any way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: try: usermod -m -G mysql root

Comment: what it will do? I am not getting it :(

Comment: put user root at mysql group.

Comment: I did that but again it says "read only file system" :(

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `df -hk | grep mnt`?

Comment: Ok. '/mnt' is used to mount volumes. You need mount a volume before  read or write.

Comment: @AndreMesquita It sounds like the partition is already mounted, but it's mounted as read-only or no_root_squash is enabled thus not allowing root to be a 'super user' anymore.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu  I have edited the question and pasted the image.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu If he send us 'cat /etc/fstab'?

Comment: what is the matter and how can I get the access of this directory?

Comment: /mnt is a root folder. You need access "/mnt/usb/" and/or "/mnt/usb1/".

Comment: cant I do anything on this? I got this done from my hosting provider. will they be able to get me access or I can also do?

Comment: See @Marqin's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it should be `chmod -R 777 jol_main` with `-R`, not `-r`.

Second, it seems that `jol_main` is on partition that is mounted as `read-only`. You can remount it as `read-write` with:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdd3 /mnt/usb
```

( or without `sudo` if you are already a root )

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, Yes it should be -R. I executed this command it says - you must specify file system type??

Comment: where to specify file system type?

Comment: @RakeshK Can you paste the corresponding entry in `/etc/fstab` for the partition you're trying to mount?

Comment: @RakeshK or give us `pwd` while beeing in that jol_main folder.

Comment: Could you paste that `pwd` output from jol_main folder? just `cd jol_main; pwd`

Comment: /mnt/usb/var/lib/mysql/jol_main